# Получение значения переменной с другого компонента

Tags: angular

Есть 2 компонента:

1. ViewComponent - таблица с данными.
2. AddEditComponent - компонент с инпутами для добавления и редактирования записей.

в зависимости от события с первого компонента ViewComponent (Нажатие AddNew или Edit) меняю значение переменной в том же компоненте (условно New = 1, Edit = 2). После открытия компонента AddEdit хочу получить значение с первого компонента, т.е. значение переменной.

в консоль на ViewComponent присваивается и выводится необходимое значение, а на AddEdit компоненте в консоль прилетает дефолтное значение с первого компонента. Т.е. не переопределенное значение после нажатия.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить текущее значение переменной.

Спасибо